# Use of /etc/passwd-, /etc/shadow-, /etc/group-

Tags: linux, user-accounts, passwd

In addition to the files : `/etc/group`, `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow`, I could see three files in my linux machine.

1. `/etc/group-`
2. `/etc/passwd-`
3. `/etc/shadow-`

I cannot see these files in my `root filesystem`. But when I try to add one user using `useradd` command, these files seem to get generated.

So i would like to know when exactly is these files created and what is the use of these files?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

These are backups of previous versions.

Manual pages show these files and states:

/etc/passwd-

Backup file for /etc/passwd.

/etc/shadow-

Backup file for /etc/shadow.

Note that this file is used by the tools of the shadow toolsuite, but not by all user and password management tools.

See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man5/shadow.5.html and http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man5/passwd.5.html